# Selenium получить скрытое значение

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium

Допустим есть скрытое поле `input`:

```
<input type="hidden" id="any_token" value="03AGdBq24Ar4jBudapX_">
```

Я бы использовал обычный поиск по `xpath` и получил бы значение:

```
token_place = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath='//*[@id="any_token"]')
token = token_place.get_attribute('value')
```

Но поле скрыто и этот метод не подходит.

Как получить значение этого поля через JS или любыми другими способами?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ситуация была такова: данный `input` генерировался в `iframe` и чтобы найти данное скрытое поле, нужно перед поиском переключиться на этот `iframe`:

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath='path_iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```